# NetLogo origin patch has NaN properties while others have 0 or empty string when using a fishnet

Tags: gis, netlogo, nan

In ArcGIS I created a shapefile using the fishnet tool, where polygons are squares and have a string attribute and an integer attribute. I want to import the fishnet to Netlogo so that it is one to one (one GIS feature to one patch).

The NetLogo world is set to have the same dimensions as the fishnet:

```
resize-world 0 94 0 104
```

For attributes I'm using the `gis:apply-coverage` command with max threshold 100 and min threshold 0. The patches look as expected and all attributes are coming across as expected, apart from `(patch 0 0)` which is the origin at the bottom left. The orgin patch is holding NaN for both strings and integers:
[image]

Why is this patch not holding the same values as all other 'empty' patches?

To set the transformation I tried using the projection file

```
gis:load-coordinate-system "data/fishnet.prj"
```

Using the envelope

```
let fishnet-dataset gis:load-dataset "data/fishnet.shp" ; polygonal (squares)
gis:set-world-envelope gis:envelope-of fishnet-dataset
```

and hard-coding

```
gis:set-transformation (list -15.08 -7.48 4.35 12.75) (list 0 94 0 104)
```

the problem occurs in all of the above options.

EDIT:

Using `gis:fill` and inspecting `(patch 0 2)` and `(patch 2 0)`:
[image: with gis:fill]

Comment: Do patches 2 0 and 0 2 have the correct empty values? Out of curiosity, have you used `gis:fill`with your vector data to confirm that it overlaps patch 0 0?